# Cosa significa "babbarella" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *La Storia*, di Elsa Morante, ho letto:

> E si metteva a balbettare: «... che ho detto?!... non volevo dire questo... non era questo che volevo dire, povera me... oh Dio oh Dio...», con poca voce, livida in faccia, portandosi le mani alla testa ricciutella e dolorante. Allora Giuseppe impietosito si faceva a consolarla: «eh, che fa?» dicendole, «non fa niente, già è passato. Mattuzza sei, **babbarella**, sei...» mentre lei se lo riguardava intontita, con occhi parlanti d’infinito amore.

So che "babbo" significa "padre", ma penso che il significato di "babbarella" in questo passaggio non abbia niente a che vedere con questo, e non sono riuscita a trovarlo su nessun dizionario. Potreste spiegarmelo?

Comment: sembra un nomignolo vezzeggiativo e affettuoso, ma non saprei indicare la sua origine

Comment: Ho letto _La Storia_ tanto tempo fa; non mi ricordo molto. Si sa questo Giuseppe di che parte d'Italia è? Il suffisso “-uzza” farebbe pensare al Sud, e in Sicilia “babbo” significa “sciocco”. Se il personaggio fosse di quelle parti, “babbarella” potrebbe valere “sciocchina”.

Comment: @DaG: Era di Calabria.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trovi *babbu* su questo dizionario del calabrese (suppongo la varietà meridionale) https://pulcinella291.forumfree.it/?t=53540796 come *stolto*.

In siciliano è lo stesso: *babbeo*, *stupido*, *stolto*. È comune in Sicilia dare della “provincia babba” a quelle confinanti: di sicuro per i catanesi, Messina è una provincia babba.

Nel brano riportato, è un vezzeggiativo: *stupidina*.